# How do i avoid runtime type checks in this code?

Tags: java

As part of the assignment, I wrote the below code to encode the 2d-array into Doubly linked list.

`RunLengthEncoding` class takes care of encode/decode functionality. Amidst implementation of this class, there was a necessity to typecast some variables to push the type check(String) at runtime.

Below are the lines that does typecasting:

```
class RunLengthEncoding {
  private DList2 list;


  private String nextRun() {
      Object obj = null;
        .....
      obj = this.list.nTh(this.sizeOfRun);
      return (String)obj;
  }

  public void check() {
          ....
      while(node != this.list.sentinel){
         int nodetype = Utility.regexChecker("\\D{1,}", (String)node.runObject, 1);
      }
  }

}
```

====================

typecast is done because, because doubly linked list(`class DList2{..}`) is a list of `DListNode2`'s which accepts and returns object of type `Object`.

```
class DListNode2{
   Object runObject;
   DListNode2 prev;
   DListNode2 next;
}
```

My question:

How should i avoid type casting in `RunLengthEncoding` class to avoid runtime type checks, when i use `DList2` class?

Note: I am a java beginner.

Comment: How does the standard java.util.LinkedList class solve that problem? How is it declared and used?

Comment: You need to use generics to avoid run time type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use generics. For example:

```
class DList<T> {
    DListNode2<T> head; // Or whatever properties your class contains
}

class DListNode2<T> {
   T runObject;
   DListNode2<T> prev;
   DListNode2<T> next;
}
```

And in your `RunLengthEncoding` class declare `list` like this: `DList<String> list;`. That way you can define the type of the parameters in your list and won't have to do casting when you retrieve your object from the list.

Take a look at the standard Java Collections API classes, for example `LinkedList`. They do this the same way.

Comment: i see `LinkedList<E>` instead of `LinkedList<T>` in java.util. what is the difference?

Comment: is this the only reason why we use generics?

Comment: You can use E, T, ... it does not matter. But general convention is to use single uppercase letter for type parameters. And as for the second question, the reason we use generics is to create classes which can be used with different data types without having to write classes for each type or having to cast Object types to desired types.

Comment: so this example is a complete example to find all reasons to use generics?